# converting a string to a c string

Tags: c++, string, c-strings

m working on some homework but don't even know where to start on this one. If you could can you throw me in the right direction. This is what i'm suppose to do

Write your own version of the str_c function that takes a C++ string as an argument (with the parameter set as a constant reference variable) and returns a pointer to the equivalent C-string. Be sure to test it with an appropriate driver.

Comment: [`return s.c_str();`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)

Comment: I think, the task is to write such a method without using the `c_str()` method. Right? See my answer for some hints. Hope they help you, without solving the task ;-)

Comment: @TobiasMende exactly correct!

Answer (score 0):

There are different possibilities to write such a function.

First, take a look at the [C++ reference for std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/), which is the starting point for your problem.

In the *Iterator section* on that page, you might find some methods which can help you to get the string character by character.

It can also help to read the documentation for the `std::string::c_str` method, you'd like to imitate: [string::c_string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/). It's important to understand, how the system works with normal C-strings (`char*`):

Due to the fact, that a C-string has now `length`- or `size`-attribute, a trick is used to determine the end of the string: The last character in the string has to be a '`\0`'.

Make sure you understand, that a `char*` string can also be seen as array of characters (char[]). This might help you, when understanding and solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

as we know, C-string is null-terminated array of char. you can put char by char from std::string to an array of char, and then closed with '\0'. and remember a pointer to a char (char*) is also representation of array of char. you can use this concept